# Performance problems jasper reports and grails/groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, jboss, jasper-reports

I am expericencing heavy performance problems with generating PDFs while using Jasper Reports in my grails application. I am invoking the jasperService:

```
def reportDef = jasperService.buildReportDefinition(parameter, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale(), [data: emptyData])
```

Running in Jboss several times, performance is good. After X hours, performance is 100+ times worse than after the start of Jboss... Response time is changing from 7-12 seconds to several minutes for creating a PDF with one single page. I am sure, that the performance lag is within this invocation, because I have added time measurements around it. As the report data is passed within the parameters, I can exclude also data base connection issues.

I have analyzed the HEAP, but it is used ~50% and not changing much during PDF creation. Overall memory is also not fully used.
I have analyzed the PermGen, but it is also far from being full.

The CPU ist permanently at 100% during creation, which is ok, knowing that PDF creation is very CPU consuming. I have ensured that no other process is holding the PDF creation up, 1st by restarting the process several times and measuring no difference, so I can exclude external interruption and 2nd) knowing that performance is much better if JBoss is restarted.

Due to the facts, I have started to analyze the JBoss itself by analyzing the Thread dumps while running the PDF creation thread. I see that nothing else is running (except the thread dumping thread), neither when it is slow nor fast after restart. I can just see that in several Thread dumps Groovy is making several AST transformations which is not strange for Groovy...

Now, I am despaired. HEAP/PermGen is ok, CPU is ok. What the hell is Jasper Reports / Grails doing?

Maybe someone has made similar experiences or an idea for the root cause? Is there something which needs/should to be cleaned up in Jasper Reports?

EDIT: My further analysis yield to the unproofed but certain outcome that JBoss 7.1.1 (latest stable) is the root cause. After installing the app on a Tomcat, everything runs smoothly, also after several days. I'll keep this open. Maybe someone has made same experience and likes to post it...? Otherwise, I will close it with this solution. I will maybe test my app on earlier versions of Jboss or 7.2/7.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that we haven't perceived that JBoss was partially ignoring our Log4J configuration and was massively logging into the server.log which we were not monitoring. Jasper and Grails plugins were writing dozens of MB for each PDF generation into the log file. After removing these log inserts, performance was good again.